# Формирование выборки для select-тэга из базы данных MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь сделать выборку из базы данных mySQL и засунуть в select, вот код:

```
<label>Страна: 
   <select class="form-control" required="required"
           id="country1" name="country1" autocomplete="on">
    <optgroup>
      <?php
        $query = "SELECT country_name_ru FROM countries LIMIT 220";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $cnt = count($row);
        for ($i=0; $i < $cnt; $i++) { 
          echo '<option>'.$row[$i].'</option>';
        }
      ?>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
  <?php 
    echo "$cnt";
    echo '<br>';
  ?>
</label>
```

Однако почему-то выводит только первую страну и потом пустую строку, хотя в базе данных 220 стран. В чем может быть дело? В чем ошибка?

Comment: Ну а сам запрос `SELECT country_name_ru FROM countries LIMIT 220;` напрямую в базу что выдаёт?

Comment: @void, там внизу уже расписали с while (не очень правильно, правда). Ошибка тупо в вызове функции.

Comment: @void выдает то, что нужно

Comment: @eprivalov1: тут в итоге осталось непонятным, помог ответ или нет. Если он всё-таки верный, отметьте его пожалуйста галочкой (а то мне тут кидают тревоги и предлагают принять за вас, что я делать не могу и не должен).

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте сначала запрос.
Если не помогло, попробуйте:

```
<label>Страна: 
   <select class="form-control" required="required"
           id="country1" name="country1" autocomplete="on">
    <optgroup>
      <?php
        $link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root')
        mysql_select_db('db')
        $query = "SELECT country_name_ru FROM countries LIMIT 220";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                echo "<option>$row</optin>";
            }
        }
      ?>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</label>
```

Comment: while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                          echo '<option>'.$row[0].'</option>';
                        }

Сейчас все вроде бы ОК, но не показывает первую страну (Россию), а начинает показывать со второй страны (Украины). Почему так происходит?

Comment: @eprivalov1 `ORDER BY` какой?

Comment: @void ORDER BY id_country пробовал, но также не показывает первую страну. Я в шоке, не могу понять почему так происходит?!

Comment: Осмелюсь предположить, и `LIMIT  0, 220` тот же самый результат?

Comment: Попробуйте так:

    $result_list = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    result_list[] = $row;
    }
    
    foreach($result_list as $row) {

    }

Comment: Надеюсь, что 

    echo "<option>$row</optin>";

из ответа, где `</optin>` вместо `</option>` не влияло на результат.